# How match regex in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, postgresql

I have `content` field in mysql/postgresql (I am thinking about which one to choose for project) database. 2 rows example:

```
row1: lorem1 <p>author: ABC</p> ipsum author dollar not text
row2: lorem2 author: ipsum author dollar not text
```

User from web page can enter `who` in input field and it must find that is `<p>{who}: (.*?)</p>` by regex. If user enters `$who = 'author'`, the result will be `ABC` only from row1. How to do that?

It will be something like:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE content LIKE '/<p>{$who}: (.*?)<\/p>/s'`

Comment: Which is it? Postgres or MySQL? Regex functions are pretty different between the two.

Comment: Is this MySQL or Postgres, and can you explain a bit more? I'm not clear on exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You mean `WHERE ...\`content\` LIKE '%<p>{$who}:%'`...? Be aware, that a leading `%` joker (same with regex if not `^` starting with) will cause performance issues on large tables because no index can be used for the query. Maybe rethink of design.

Comment: Beware of SQL injection

Comment: Not possible (or at least much too messy) to do in MySQL's SQL.  MariaDB has `regexp_replace`; perhaps the Postgres answer applies.

Comment: thank you for your answers. I am thinking about which database to choose for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres you can use [`regexp_replace()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html).

Example data:

```
create table example (id int, str text);
insert into example values
(1, 'lorem1 <p>author: ABC</p> ipsum author dollar not text'),
(2, 'lorem2 author: ipsum author dollar not text');
```

Query:

```
select id, trim(r) result
from 
    example, 
    regexp_replace(str, '^.*?<p>author:(.*?)</p>.*$', '\1') r
where r <> str;

 id | result 
----+--------
  1 | ABC
(1 row)
```